# Connection pool vs separate connections

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling

In my program I am accessing a wep api. There can be up to 7 different threads accessing different servers of the web api. Each thread is responsible for one server - and each server rate limits each thread. Each thread updates the same mysql database. The number of threads remains constant.

In my example situation, is there any need for a connection pool? Shouldn't I just open 7 different connections that will be open for the life of the program?

Answer (score -1):

Use a pool.  Network disruptions occur.  Databases kill connections after max. lifetime settings.  Firewalls and load balancers terminate connections.

As the author I am naturally biased, but I recommend [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with pools. Will the pool attempt to reconnect to the server under these circumstances? Or do pool managers usually take care of it?

Comment: The pool will handle the reconnects.